# Rails Deprecated Warning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been trying to get rid of these deprecated warnings for 2 weeks now with no luck. Would truly be grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.

First Warning

```
WARNING: using the built-in Timeout class which is known to have issues when used for         opening connections. Install the SystemTimer gem if you want to make sure the Redis client will not hang.
```

Second Warning

```
/Users/ChuckJHardy/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.02/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:101:Warning: Gem::LoadError#version_requirement= is deprecated and will be removed on or after January 2011. Use #requirement.
```

Third Warning

```
/Users/ChuckJHardy/Code/Sites/www/vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:119:Warning: Gem::Dependency#version_requirements is deprecated and will be removed on or after August 2010.  Use #requirement
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, a sideways solution. Place this in your Environments or Initializers file.

```
ActiveSupport::Deprecation.silenced = true
```

Answer (score 3):

The first error is coming from REDIS. Judging by a [quick googling](https://github.com/ezmobius/redis-rb/blob/master/lib/redis/client.rb), it's coming when Redis is trying to load the gem system_timer. Try adding that to your gems and see if it resolves.

The second and third error appear to be [this problem](http://www.mattvsworld.com/blog/2010/03/version_requirements-deprecated-warning-in-rails/) in rails 2.3.5 and ruby enterprise edition. More information on the [lighthouse ticket](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/4026) including a couple of fixes.

Comment: Well I followed both and did what Phillip Koebbe did in the lighthouse ticket. Yet I still have the exact same warnings. Thank you for your time and efforts.

Answer (score 2):

For the first one, just install the SystemTimer gem as instructed.

```
rvmsudo gem install systemtimer
```

For the next two, upgrade rubygems.

```
rvmsudo gem update --system
```

Comment: ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'systemtimer' (>= 0) in any repository

Comment: Sorry about that - Pressed Enter to quick - Have tried the two about. System Time simply gives the not found error and Rubygems says Nothing to update. Thoughts

Comment: rvmsudo gem install SystemTimer Works

Comment: Not sure about the latter two, then - they're checking if the `Gem::LoadError` and `Gem::Dependency` objects respond to `requirements` rather than `version_requirements` - not sure why it'd be failing if you're on the latest version of rubygems.